# What is purpose of such interface who has all the default methods inside

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

for reference check this interface :
**org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer**

This interface has all the default method with empty body.

*why they just not declared interface instead of empty body in interface??*

Comment: because you can just customize the corresponding method with that functionality

Comment: Seems this is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575191/where-are-the-default-methods-of-webmvcconfigurer

Comment: New JDK 8 feature for interfaces.  One artifact instead of two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This interface has default callback methods which can be implemented to customize the  default configuration.Previously an abstract class `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` implemented `WebMvcConfigurer` but now `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` class is deprecated and the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface itself has default methods.